# Code for uploading a video on my web page

Tags: html, firebase, web

I have a code for a web page, which can handle image uploading, but not video uploading. The page is built using Javascript and Html. This is the HTML code for the page to post a new picture. Would it be different for a video page? And also, do I need to update my JS code too?

```
<!-- Post new pic page -->
    <section id="page-add" class="mdl-grid fp-content" style="display: none;">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">
        <div class="fp-addcontainer mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
          <div class="fp-overlay">
            <i class="material-icons">hourglass_full</i>
          </div>
          <img id="newPictureContainer" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPhfDwAChwGA60e6kgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="New Picture to Upload">
          <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
            <form id="uploadPicForm" action="#">
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="imageCaptionInput">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="imageCaptionInput">Image caption...</label>
              </div>
              <br />
              <button type="submit" class="fp-upload mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-color--amber-400">
                Upload this pic!
              </button>
            </form>
            <div class="fp-legalese-add">
              All uploaded pictures will be publicly viewable, and must adhere to the <a href="/terms">Terms of Service</a>.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This looks like a partial page, it would be helpful to know what javascript is associated with this and also if there is existing back-end code most likely PHP or c#

Comment: Hey Danimal, this is the GitHub repository from where I cloned the code. https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web. Does this help? I'm so confused with this.

Comment: This was designed specifically for uploading photos only. If you want to mess around with it I would look at uploader.js @ line 140 and start from there. Your best bet is to create your own rather than try to use a square peg in a round hole. This way you will also be able to understand how uploading works and how to do it with firebase.  You should also tag your questions with the language/technology you are using to get people who specifically know that tech to answer the finer points.  As it happens I do not know enough about firebase to help.